# Change API Gateway Name when using Serverless Framework

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

The Serverless framework has made it very easy for developers to create an API gateway connected to a lambda function. like this

```
hello:
  name: hello-handler
  description: blablabla
  handler: /lambda-functions/hello-handler.handler
  role: HelloRole
  package:
    include:
      - lambda-functions/hello-handler.js
  events:
    - http: GET hello
```

My question is how can I change the name of the API gateway that is going to be created?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/), this should do the trick.

```
provider:
  ...
  apiName: custom-api-name # Use a custom name for the API Gateway API
```

Comment: Thanks! I should look harder next time lol... I was looking only at the [API docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/) and elsewhere...